# inequality of elliptic PDE with Dirichlet-Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, cauchy-problem

The problem is given as follows

‎\begin{equation}‎
‎\begin{array}{lc}‎
‎\Delta u (\textbf{x}) = h(\textbf{x}), ‎& \textbf{x} \in \Omega‎ ,‎\\‎
‎u(\textbf{x}) = f(\textbf{x})‎, ‎& \textbf{x} \in \Gamma_1‎ ,‎\\‎
‎\frac{\partial u}{ \partial \nu} = g(\textbf{x})‎, ‎& \textbf{x} \in \Gamma_1‎ ,‎\\‎
‎\end{array}‎
‎\end{equation}‎
where $\Gamma_1$ is a subset of $\partial\Omega‎$, the boundary of $\Omega‎$.

I want to know where I can find the proof of the following inequality (in which space there is the one)?

‎\begin{equation}‎
\Vert u \Vert \leq C (\Vert h \Vert + \Vert f \Vert + \Vert g \Vert),
‎\end{equation}‎
where $C$ is a constant depending only on $\Omega‎$.

In *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order*, Gilbarg-Trudinger, I found the inequality for the Dirichlet one in $W^{1,2}(\Omega‎)$ space, but for my problem, I failed to adapt it.

Comment: Do you mean $\partial \Omega \setminus \Gamma_1$ for one of the boundary conditions, or are you actually interested in the Cauchy problem as stated?

Comment: Both the Dirichlet-Neumann boundary conditions are on $\Gamma _1$. The Cauchy problem is stated.

Comment: In that case you will probably not find estimates of this type except either (1) in trivial-and-overdetermined cases (like $\Gamma_1 = \partial \Omega$) or (2) in spaces of analytic functions, under analyticity assumptions on $\Gamma_1$. Granted, the Cauchy problem for elliptic equations is potentially complicated, but not in ways that lead to well-posedness outside the analytic case.

Comment: Thanks. For case (1) like $\Gamma _1 = \partial \Omega$, is there any references?

Comment: Moreover, is another inequality for Cauchy problem (something like the one I need to find)?

Comment: For case (1) you can use your favorite theorems for either the Dirichlet or the Neumann problem, as it solves both (!). The tricky thing is that it's overdetermined, so you are extremely unlikely to be able to find a solution $u$ given $h, f, g, $ and $\Omega$. Solving the Cauchy problem can be done with (variants/modifications of) the Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem. This does in principle come with "estimates," but everything needs to be analytic (and it's difficult to decide whether you actually get a solution on the entirety of $\Omega$ or not).

Comment: In the particular case $\Gamma_1 = \partial \Omega$, $h=-1$, and $g$ is constant then we must have $\Omega$ is a ball (this is called Serrin’s overdetermined problem)